# Transform Json Array

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-collection

I have a json like this being retrieved by my model:

```
[
    {
      "type": "seat",
      "number": 4
    },
    {
      "type": "seat",
      "number": 8
    },
    {
      "type": "seat",
      "number": 12
    },
    {
      "type": "seat",
      "number": 16
    }
]
```

However due to some poorly written code in the API I'm working with I need to get the above json looking this instead:

```
{
  "4" : [ "{\"number\":\"4\",\"type\":\"seat\"}" ],
  "8" : [ "{\"number\":\"8\",\"type\":\"seat\"}" ],
  "12" : [ "{\"number\":\"12\",\"type\":\"seat\"}" ],
  "16" : [ "{\"number\":\"16\",\"type\":\"seat\"}" ]
}
```

I would like to know how I can transform the first example to look like the second example using collections in laravel.

Comment: Lol if this question is too broad then I'm very confused now.

Comment: And I'm confused how a question rated -3 in the beginning receives so much positive attention suddenly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems pretty straight forward:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);

collect($data)
    ->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
        return [$item['number'] => [json_encode($item)]];
    })
    ->toArray();
```

Comment: Alright, thanks will give this a try :)